# Automatic select of drop down list based on the first letter of typed text in input jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I tried to search something equivalent without success, this is not a php based value where one drop down updates another. its  a simpler version but I don't know how to proceed

Basically I have a text field like

```
 <input size="50" name="productname" id="product" type="text" />

 <select name="platform">
    <?php if($manufacturers) foreach($manufacturers as $each) { ?>
           <option value="<?=$each['id']?>"><?=$each[ 'manufacturerName']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

I noticed that in about 90% of my scenario if a manufacturer name is Samsung
most of its product will start with S that is the first name of the manufacturer.

In my select I have some manufacturers 
for example , Samsung, Alcatel, Hitachi, from a database.

In this form I am doing user will be adding new product, for example Samsung S6, as he types Samsung, I wish a jquery will set the selected option to the select list to samsung most probably based on the first matching letter.

Comment: Show us your javascript then...

Comment: you need to use ajax on a change event to fetch a ordered list of options the closes match being on top

Comment: $("#chipname").on("change keyup paste", function(){
   console.log($("#chipname").val().charAt(0));
  }) with this i get the first letter but i dont know how to loop in the select and set the value to selected based on its value starting with this letter

Comment: `if ($('option').text().charAt(0) != $("#chipname").val().charAt(0)) ) {$('this').hide();}`

Comment: hello madalin thanks for the answer about hide, however this wouldnt be suitable in my case, as it does happen that for example a manufacturer whose name starts with S does not brand his telephone starting with S. if i hide the options not starting with s i might hide the correct manufacturer, this was just an option to help the guy filling the form when new phone is released, if the incorect manufacturer is selected he can still manually select other, norli's answer fitted good. I am sad the question was voted -1 because I already have only 8 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, then you can modified with your own creativity.

```
$('#product').on('keyup', function () {
   var input_val = String($(this).val());
   var sel = $('select[name=platform]');

   if (input_val !== "") {
      var h = $('select option[value*=' + input_val + ']');
      if (h.length > 0) {
          h.prop('selected', true);
      } else {
          sel.val("");
      }
   } else {
      sel.val("");
   }

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/1modLb0r/1/)**

Comment: $("#product").on("change keyup paste", function(){
   var valuefound ='';
   $("#platformid option").each(function(i){
   if($(this).text().substring(0, 2).toLowerCase() ==$("#product").val().substring(0, 2).toLowerCase() ){
    valuefound = $(this).val();
   }
  
  });
  $('option:selected', 'select[name="platformid"]').removeAttr('selected');
  $('#platformid option[value="' + valuefound + '"]').prop('selected', true);
  })  i formulated this based on the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [jQueryUI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Below code gets necessary data first from the database and load it into the element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input size="50" name="productname" id="product" type="text" />
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) { 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
?>
    <script language="javascript">
        var availableTags = [
        <?php echo "\"".$row['manufacturerName']."\","; ?>
        ];
        $("#product").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    </script>
<?php }
    } ?>
```

Comment: cannot use dynamically loaded content because firstly the product which is being typed does not exist in the database so i am just using the script to make a raw guess based on the first letter, compare with the manufacturer and hand set for example tomorow samsung can launch a mobile calling it Wawa, and a company may exist as wanadoo. so the list of manufacturer should be there, i am just helping him to pre select one, if its not ok he can still choose another from the list...